# Importing csv with unquoted strings with commas; for every line- ignoring every 3rd comma onwards?

Tags: r, csv

I have a .csv file which has 3 target columns- an IP address, timestamp, and some data. The address and timestamp are seperated by a single comma and have no commas within them; but the data field has commas in there. For instance, here's the first 4 entries from the file-

```
142.XX.XXX.XXX,2019-03-13T23:52:07.449219,abc
192.XX.XXX.XXX,2019-03-13T23:52:11.965405,
13.XX.XXX.XXX,2019-03-13T23:52:09.903720,HTTPWed, 13 Mar 2019,XXXXXX,
71.XX.XXX.XXX,2019-03-13T23:52:23.529145,HTTP/1.1/n\n
```

Each entry is guaranteed to occupy only one line; and will follow the following format; where data can have 0 to n commas in it-
`ip_adr,timestamp,data`

Is there any way to read in the .csv file while ignoring/removing every 3rd comma onwards for a given line?

I've tried setting FLUSH=TRUE which according to what I read should have helped solve it, but it didn't. How can I modify my read.csv statement in a way to solve this problem?

`data <- read.csv(file="D:/Shodan/data.csv", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, skipNul = TRUE, flush=TRUE)`

Comment: Can you pre-process the file outside R using e.g. `awk`? This is a perfect fit for something like `awk -F"," 'BEGIN{ OFS=","}{print $1,$2,$3} yourfile.csv > newfile.csv'`

Comment: I have GitBash installed so I can definitely give it a try! Can you include that as an answer with any formatting in place? It definitely sounds like an answer that could work! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using `stri_split_fixed`:

```
library(data.table)
library(stringi)

x <- readLines('test.txt')
res <- transpose(stri_split_fixed(x, ',', n = 3))
as.data.table(res)

#                V1                         V2                           V3
# 1: 142.XX.XXX.XXX 2019-03-13T23:52:07.449219                          abc
# 2: 192.XX.XXX.XXX 2019-03-13T23:52:11.965405                             
# 3:  13.XX.XXX.XXX 2019-03-13T23:52:09.903720 HTTPWed, 13 Mar 2019,XXXXXX,
# 4:  71.XX.XXX.XXX 2019-03-13T23:52:23.529145                HTTP/1.1/n\\n
```

Comment: This worked! It read in all my lines as is (1,000,100 of them), and then split them on the first 3 commas correctly. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

**1) strcapture** Use `strcapture` where Lines is given in Note at the end.  No packages are used.

```
# L <- trimws(readLines("myfile.dat"))
L <- trimws(readLines(textConnection(Lines)))
L <- L[L != ""]
strcapture("^(.*?),(.*?),(.*)", L, 
  list(ip_adr = character(0), timestamp = character(0), data = character(0)))
```

giving:

```
          ip_adr                  timestamp                         data
1 142.XX.XXX.XXX 2019-03-13T23:52:07.449219                          abc
2 192.XX.XXX.XXX 2019-03-13T23:52:11.965405                             
3  13.XX.XXX.XXX 2019-03-13T23:52:09.903720 HTTPWed, 13 Mar 2019,XXXXXX,
4  71.XX.XXX.XXX 2019-03-13T23:52:23.529145                   HTTP/1.1/n
```

**2) sub/read.table** Another possibility is to replace the first two commas with semicolon, say, and then read it in using the semicolon separator.  L is from above:

```
read.table(text = sub(",", ";", sub(",", ";", L)), sep = ";", as.is = TRUE,
  col.names = c("ip_addr", "timestamp", "data"))
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "142.XX.XXX.XXX,2019-03-13T23:52:07.449219,abc
192.XX.XXX.XXX,2019-03-13T23:52:11.965405,
13.XX.XXX.XXX,2019-03-13T23:52:09.903720,HTTPWed, 13 Mar 2019,XXXXXX,
71.XX.XXX.XXX,2019-03-13T23:52:23.529145,HTTP/1.1/n\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `unite` after reading the csv and combine the columns

```
df <- read.csv("path_of_file.csv", header = FALSE)
```

In your example, you want `3:5` columns combined so we can do

```
tidyr::unite(df, data, paste0("V", 3:5), sep = " ")

#              V1                         V2                        data
#1 142.XX.XXX.XXX 2019-03-13T23:52:07.449219                         abc
#2 192.XX.XXX.XXX 2019-03-13T23:52:11.965405                          
#3  13.XX.XXX.XXX 2019-03-13T23:52:09.903720 HTTPWed  13 Mar 2019 XXXXXX
#4  71.XX.XXX.XXX 2019-03-13T23:52:23.529145               HTTP/1.1/n\\n
```

---

Using base R you can also use `apply` row-wise and `paste` the columns together

```
df$data <- apply(df[3:5], 1, paste0, collapse = " ")
```

You might want to delete the unwanted columns (`V3:V5`) later.

Comment: The import statement forces the rows to be the same size and "shifts" columns up to fit the row. This is avoidable by including `flush=TRUE` in the read.csv. To that end- without the flush; I have 1,000,100 rows, and am only getting back ~560k of them. The tidyr solution works though and collapses the rows properly.